# Testing user login with powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I am using a script on powershell to test user logins on a remote server elsewhere but i am getting an error.
The code i am using is

```
Get-WmiObject -Class win32_account -ComputerName $ComputerName
```

And the error i am getting is:

```
gwmi : Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
At line:21 char:21
+ $logon_sessions = @(gwmi win32_logonsession -ComputerName $computername)
+                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo      : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-WmiObject], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
```

Can someone please help me.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to test for these logins?

Comment: im testing to make sure that users are still available after an update has happened on a server